# Setting a cookie in express is not working across localhost domains

Tags: node.js, express, cookies

I have the following two endpoints on my express server:

```
api.get(
  "/register",
  asyncMiddleware( async (req, res) => {
    res.cookie("TEST", "value", {});
    res.sendStatus(200);
  })
);

api.get(
  "/home",
  asyncMiddleware( async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.cookies);
    res.sendStatus(200);
  })
)
```

I'm hosting the above endpoints at `localhost:3010`. I'm also running a front-end server that's hosted on `localhost:3000`. When I call the `/register` endpoint from the front-end, and then call the `/home` endpoint, the `console.log(req.cookies)` comes back with an empty object. However, calling the `/register` endpoint from `localhost:3010` will set the cookie as intended, and the console log will show the correct value.

Are there any special steps I need to take to get cookies working across domains in Express? I've looked around the documentation and couldn't follow anything relevant.

Comment: sometimes browser blocks the cookies from an unsecured http host. try to accept cookies manually if not accepted automatically

Comment: Update: figured it out. Had to set the "withCredentials" option to true when using axios, or else the cookies wouldn't send.

Answer (score 0):

To use cookies in express you need to install the `cookie-parser` package:

`npm install cookie-parser`

Then add it as a middleware before your routes:

```js
const express = require('express')
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')

const api = express()
api.use(cookieParser())

api.get(
  "/register",
  asyncMiddleware( async (req, res) => {
    res.cookie("TEST", "value", {});
    res.sendStatus(200);
  })
);

api.get(
  "/home",
  asyncMiddleware( async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.cookies);
    res.sendStatus(200);
  })
)
```

Check the docs for more details:
http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cookie-parser.html